# Fill in checkbox on iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to modify an existing PDF with iText. My code currently edits text fields nicely, but I cant get it to tick or un-tick a checkbox.

```
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(INPUTFILE);
                int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();

                PdfStamper filledOutForm = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("WrittenForm.pdf"));

                AcroFields fields = filledOutForm.getAcroFields();

                //not working
                fields.setField("checkbox", "On");

                //working
                fields.setField("textfield1", "infinite road");
                fields.setField("textfield2", "jayboy");


                filledOutForm.close();
```

Any ideas?

SOLVED:

```
 String states[] = fields.getAppearanceStates("checkbox");

//prints array values - returns 'yes, no'

 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(states));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I [saw here](http://threebit.net/mail-archive/itext-questions/msg03326.html), you need to check the available states using:

```
String[] states = fields.getAppearanceStates("checkbox");
```

And then set the state according to the options in this `String[]`

Comment: Awesome -- very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

While

```
fields.getAppearanceStates("checkbox");
```

usually does return the correct value, on some of my checkboxes for whatever reason this returned an empty array.  Looking at the form in Acrobat Pro I found that the proper string to send to setField is called "Export Value" in the "Options" tab of the field properties.  You can change it there as well.

Answer (score -2):

```
filledOutForm.setFormFlattening(true);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.